# ChartJS - Issues with positioning and viewing various components of horizontal bar

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I have a React `HorizontalBar` component being used like so:

```
<div>
    <HorizontalBar data={myData} options={myOptions} height={80} />
</div>
```

The options supplied are:

```
{
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'My Title',
    },
    tooltips: { enabled: false },
    hover: { mode: null },
    legend: { display: false },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
        },
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 0,
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [
            {
                position: 'top',
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    sampleSize: 2,
                    callback: function (value: number, index: any, values: any) {
                        if (value == 0 || value == 100) {
                            return value;
                        }
                        return '';
                    },
                },
                stacked: true,
            },
        ],
        yAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
    },
};
```

Currently, this is what it looks like. I've added a background color on the canvas to show you what is going on:

[image]

Several things are wrong here that I would like some help on:

1. I cannot figure out why there is some mysterious padding on the left side of my canvas.
2. I would like to compress the distance between the gradient bar and the title but nothing I've tried in regards to adding `padding` options to the `title` attribute seem to work.
3. Finally, there is actually supposed to be a data label that is clipped because the size of the canvas. If I adjust the height attribute of the `HorizontalBar` to 140, it reveals:

[image]

Basically, what I want is that data label to be shown without everything so vertically stretched out (and without the y-axis line that has appeared in the second photo).

I want it to look something like this:

[image]

How do I achieve that?

Edit: I figured out the y-axis line display issue. I just have to add `gridLines: { display: false }` to my `yAxes` option and that removes it.

Answer (score 0):

- Title has its own padding, defaulting to 10.
- yAxis can be hidden totally to remove the space (display: false).
- tickMarkLength can be set to a negative number for xAxis grid lines to move those labels closer.
- You should add padding to the bottom for the data label.